# Parameters estimation using Kalman filter

Tags: time-series, optimization, kalman-filter

I have a model like this:
$$P_t=\alpha_t+gP_{t-1}+u_t$$

$$\alpha_t=\alpha_{t-1}+d+n_t$$
Where {$u_t$} and {$n_t$} are normal, iid with 0 mean but unknown variance.

I want to estimate the parameters $g$ and $d$, and all I have is a series of $P_t$. Can I solve this problem by using Kalman Filter? If yes, how to do this with pykalman (or some other python packages); if no, what else can I use?

This problem origins from an empirical study about market quality, you can find the paper here:
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0378426608000393

Comment: "Can I solve this problem by using Kalman Filter?" <- yes! (depending on what you mean by solve)

Comment: By saying "solve" I mean "get reliable estimations of the parameters" :)